# OneNote Add in: Getting HTML content

Tags: office-js, onenote, onenote-api

In the [example](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/onenote/richtext), code is provided to get RichText. It is able to get the **plain** text content of the page, but I cannot seem to get it to return the **HTML** formatted content of the page.

For example:

> Header:
>
> - A
> - B

should be:

```
<p>Header:</p>
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

However, the example code uses `richText/text` and only returns `Header:`. Is it possible to do something like **`richText/HTML`** and get the HTML shown above? (Note: I want to use the **add-in** only, not the OneNote REST API.)

Thanks!

Code snippet from documentation:

```
OneNote.run(function (context) {

// Get the collection of pageContent items from the page.
var pageContents = context.application.getActivePage().contents;

// Get the first PageContent on the page, and then get its outline's paragraphs.
var outlinePageContents = [];
var paragraphs = [];
var richTextParagraphs = [];
// Queue a command to load the id and type of each page content in the outline.
pageContents.load("id,type");

// Run the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
return context.sync()
    .then(function () {
        // Load all page contents of type Outline
        $.each(pageContents.items, function(index, pageContent) {
            if(pageContent.type == 'Outline')
            {
                pageContent.load('outline,outline/paragraphs,outline/paragraphs/type');
                outlinePageContents.push(pageContent);
            }
        });
        return context.sync();
    })
    .then(function () {
        // Load all rich text paragraphs across outlines
        $.each(outlinePageContents, function(index, outlinePageContent) {
            var outline = outlinePageContent.outline;
            paragraphs = paragraphs.concat(outline.paragraphs.items);
        });
        $.each(paragraphs, function(index, paragraph) {
            if(paragraph.type == 'RichText')
            {
                richTextParagraphs.push(paragraph);
                paragraph.load("id,richText/text");
            }
        });
        return context.sync();
    })
    .then(function () {
        // Display all rich text paragraphs to the console
        $.each(richTextParagraphs, function(index, richTextParagraph) {
            var richText = richTextParagraph.richText;
            console.log("Paragraph found with richtext content : " + richText.text + " and richtext id : " + richText.id);
        });
        return context.sync();
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: What are the properties available on the `richTextParagraph.richText` object?  Is there an html one among them?  If so, what is its return type?

Comment: Properties are `id` and `text` only (both of type `String`). Per https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/onenote/richtext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We haven't documented it yet (it will added very soon), but there is a "getHtml()" method on the richText object. Here is a sample snippet.

```
OneNote.run(function (context) {

    var outline = context.application.getActiveOutlineOrNull();

    outline.load('id, type, paragraphs/id, paragraphs/type');

    return context.sync().then(function () {
        if (!outline.isNull) {
            var richTextParagraphs = [];
            var htmls = [];
            console.log("outline id: " + outline.id);
            for(var i = 0;  i < outline.paragraphs.items.length; i++){
                var paragraph = outline.paragraphs.items[i];
                console.log("paragraph type " + paragraph.type);
                if (paragraph.type == "RichText"){
                    richTextParagraphs.push(paragraph);
                    var html = paragraph.richText.getHtml();
                    htmls.push(html);
                    paragraph.load("richtext/id, richtext/languageid")
                }
            }

            return context.sync().then(function(){
                for(var i = 0; i < richTextParagraphs.length; i++){
                    var richTextParagraph = richTextParagraphs[i];
                    console.log("Rich text paragraph id: " + richTextParagraph.richText.Id + " and " + richTextParagraph.richText.languageId)
                }
                for(var i = 0; i < htmls.length; i++){
                    var html = htmls[i];
                    console.log("Rich text paragraph html: " + html.value)
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
        console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
});
```

Comment: Note this isn't full page HTML, only at the rich text level. The function above also doesn't take into account all rich text objects, there might be more in the page (inside tables, in sub paragraphs...)

Comment: Jorge, thanks for the quick reply. The code above is throwing my a syntax error warning in Chrome. I figured it might be a copy and paste problem, so I wrote it out by hand, but then I got the error: `Error: ValueNotLoaded: The value of the result object has not been loaded yet. Before reading the value property, call "context.sync()" on the associated request context.` Could you please clarify?

Comment: I've updated the code and tested it. It should work now.

Comment: Is it possible to get the HTML from a table object, or do I have to iterate though each cell of the table to get the HTML?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You'll have to iterate.